# How to use CopyRect method in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm loading an image from disk and want to copy (part of) it to a second TImage:

```
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(S);
with Image1.Picture.Bitmap do
  Image2.Canvas.CopyRect(Image2.Canvas.ClipRect, Canvas, Canvas.ClipRect);
```

Image2 just shows a white rectangle, and Image1 doesn't show the file from disk. If I remove the second statement Image1 does show the image. (Strangest thing: if I only comment out the CopyRect statement and leave the "with" line (empty statement) Image1 doesn't show either!)

How do I use CopyRect to copy part of an image?

**edit**
When I split the two statements into two separate actions (buttons) the following happens:

1. Image loads and shows in Image1
2. Image1 disappears(!), and Image2 shows a white rectangle.

BTW, I'm using Delphi 2009.

Comment: I copypasted your code and it works just fine for me. Try separating both statements (in 2 buttons) and see what happens

Comment: It's not strange: `Image1.Picture.Bitmap` forces the type of the graphic to hold a 'bitmap'. If `Image1.Picture` is not already a bitmap (which would seem so, although missing in the question), the graphic frees it and creates a bitmap.

Comment: @Magicmaster - Thanks, but doesn't seem to work. I added to my question.

Comment: That's why @Magic's code is working, he's loading a 'bitmap'.

Comment: @Sertac - What code by Magic are you referring to?

Comment: @steve - The same code, it's only that he's loading a bitmap and you're loading another type of graphic. Either that.., or I'll delete all of my comments.. :)

Comment: @steve - Can you confirm please you're not loading a bitmap, and whether if your code works if `s` points to a bitmap file?

Comment: @Sertac - I'm feeling forced to use the picture property because I can't load to an image's canvas. But then I can't use the image's canvas to copy from. Frankly I'm a bit confused by the difference between the picture and the canvas.

Comment: @stevenvh: What is the file name `S`? In particular, what is the file *extension*? Is it 'bmp', 'png', 'jpg', ... ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TCanvas.CopyRect` copies the rectangle by using `StretchBlt`. StretchBlt requires a bitmap. If you're loading any other graphic type to your image then its `Picture.Bitmap` is empty. In fact the bitmap gets created just when you refer to it: `with Image1.Picture.Bitmap do`.

You can use a temporary bitmap for the cause:

```
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(S);

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bmp.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);

    with Bmp do
      Image2.Canvas.CopyRect(Image2.Canvas.ClipRect, Canvas, Canvas.ClipRect);
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  ..
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. Now I just have to get the colors right :-(