# CopyRect (scaling) with the correct colors in Delphi

Tags: delphi, colors

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360368/how-to-use-copyrect-method-in-delphi) I asked about the correct use of the CopyRect method. I got an answer which fixed my problem, but now the colors of the copied rectangle are wrong (limited to 256 values?).
This is the code:

```
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(SomeJPGimage);

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bmp.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);
    with Bmp do
      Image2.Canvas.CopyRect(Image2.Canvas.ClipRect, Canvas, Canvas.ClipRect);
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

The inset with the false colors is Image2. The colors are right if I don't resize.
How do I get the 24 bit color of the source image (a JPG) when resizing?

**edit**
Draw is not an alternative; I want to copy a scaled version of part of the source image.

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue. I guess what you're seeing is result of resizing, you're probably shrinking the image. Do this test: grab http://www.spronkey.com/sdc-gradients.png , and convert it to jpg. Run your code loading this image but **without resizing the image**. I used a colorful part of the image: `Image2.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0,0,300,74), Canvas, Rect(460,1076,760,1150));`   This part has 599 unique colors before converting to jpg and about 8000 unique colors after converting. Duplicate the test with different parts of the image if you want.I bet you won't notice any color reduction.

Comment: RGB cube part is even better for test, 16384 colors before converting `Image2.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0,0,128,128),Canvas,Rect(1118,683,1246,811));`

Comment: @Sertac - The false colors seem to be the result of the resizing, not of the CopyRect as such. I'll adjust my question: Is there a way to resize and keep the true colors?

Comment: I was writing a post attempting to answer that question at the time you were modifying your question. :) See if it answers..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not caused because of color reduction, or a wrong pixelformat etc.. You're probably shrinking the image while copying and 'StretchBlt' compresses the image to fit in, and depending on the mode, produces some artifacts. For instance the below 128x128 image 
   [image]

is displayed exactly the same if no resizing is applied. However if it is applied on a 90x100 image for instance, the output is 
  [image].

You can change the [stretching mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a slightly better result:

```
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(SomeJPGimage);

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bmp.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);

    SetStretchBltMode(Image2.Canvas.Handle, HALFTONE);  // <- here

    with Bmp do
      Image2.Canvas.CopyRect(Image2.Canvas.ClipRect, Canvas, Canvas.ClipRect);
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For the above source picture the output now becomes:
[image]

(Having browsed a little 'graphics.pas', the VCL seems to be using halftone only for 8-bit images. I may be wrong or right in this assessment, but in any case halftone stretching mode has no such constraint.)

For anything better, I believe, you have to use a proper graphics library.

Comment: Excellent! The `SetStretchBltMode` seems to do the trick. Thanks a million.

Comment: Your example just shows aliasing banding, as does the grayscale gradient, but my example had false colors, i.e. colors not present in the original. Probably the effect of a gradient vs a 'real' picture.

Answer (score 4):

Edited again:

Turns out the issue is going against the WRONG canvas (too easy with TImage if you're not used to it).  Tried to save files on my last sample and got a huge file on the one I assigned.  So I Started looking into some of the other values and found that you need to work against the Bitmap Canvas...

```
var
  BMP: TBitmap;
  MyClipRect: TRect;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
     begin
       Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
       Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
       try
         Bmp.Assign(Image1.Picture.Graphic);
         myClipRect.Left := (Bmp.Width div 2);
         myClipRect.Top := (Bmp.Height div 2);
         myClipRect.Right := (Bmp.Width);
         myClipRect.Bottom := (Bmp.Height);

         with Image2.Picture.Bitmap do
           begin
             Width := Bmp.Width div 2;
             Height := Bmp.Height div 2;
             Canvas.CopyRect(Canvas.ClipRect, Bmp.Canvas, MyClipRect);
           end;
         Image2.Picture.SaveToFile('image2.bmp');
      finally
        Bmp.Free;
      end;
   end;
end;
```

Hope that finally got it.  Yeesh.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I have to use CopyRect because I want to copy a scaled version of part of the source image, so Draw won't do.

Comment: Sure it will.  I'm saying to Assign or Draw the image, THEN do your CopyRect.  It's working for me here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you use Image2 as an intermediate image, and then CopyRect from it to a third image? I tried this but, while the Draw works fine, the CopyRect spoils it. Can you post your complete code?

Comment: Edited.  Hope that explains what I was trying to say and helps out.