# Take screenshot of specific part of screen

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-2007

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a specific part of the screen. Here is the coordinates of the part of the screen i want to 'cut' :

Left : 442
Top : 440
Right : 792
Bottom : 520

That is, a rectangle of width 350px and height of 80px. But i don't know how to use CopyRect to achieve this task, instead i'm getting a blank image. Here is my code :

```
function screenshot: boolean;
var
  Bild : TBitmap;
  c: TCanvas;
  rect_source, rect_destination : TRect;
begin
   c := TCanvas.Create;
   bild := tbitmap.Create;
   c.Handle := GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow);
   try
     rect_source := Rect(0, 0, Screen.Width, Screen.Height);
     rect_destination := Rect(442,440,792,520);
     Bild.Width := 350;
     Bild.Height := 80;
     Bild.Canvas.CopyRect(rect_destination, c, rect_source);
     Bild.savetofile('c:\users\admin\desktop\screen.bmp');
   finally
    ReleaseDC(0, c.Handle);
     Bild.free;
     c.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360368/how-to-use-copyrect-method-in-delphi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing here is copying the whole screen and draw it at coordinate `Rect(442,440,792,520);` in your new bitmap... Which is off its canvas.

The coordinate `Rect(442,440,792,520)` correspond to the part you want to get from the source bitmap. You want to copy it "inside" your new bitmap, so within the rect `Rect(0,0,350,80)`

You can simply adjust your rect like this :

```
 rect_source := Rect(442,440,792,520);
 rect_destination := Rect(0,0,350,80);
```

The rest of your code seems correct.